# IE7 jquery z-index

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

Got a website with a menu going in front of a jquery slider.
In IE7 the drop down menu goes behind the menu.

The website is: http://lkanlaeg.stom.dk/

What have i tried so far?

- The jquery fix, which didn't work.
- Positioning all top elements to "relative and" setting the z-index accordingly.

What would you suggest i try next?
Repeat the positioning process?
My code was something like:

```
#wrapper, .content-wrapper, #header-wrapper, #primary-menu, #new-royalslider-1, #primary-menu ul{
position: relative;
z-index: auto;
```

Plus

```
#primary-menu ul li ul{
z-index: 900;
position: absolute;
```

Am i wrong here?

The only "half solution" i have found is setting the z-index of the slider to -1 - that actually helps.. But i feel like its more of a last-option.

Comment: Is the drop down menu going behind the menu or behind the slider in IE7?

Comment: Its a drop down menu going behind the slide when activated.
Sorry for any confusion on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first `content-wrapper` on line 75 I added `style="z-index:10;"` and on the second `content-wrapper` on line 142 I added `z-index:5;` to the style block. This fixed it right up.

The top wrapper needs to be greater than the body, this will push the menu above everything. I tested this in browserstack and it works fine.

[image]